# function composition and identity functions proof

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

I have to prove this:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and suppose $f: A \rightarrow B$ is one-to-one and onto. Then $f^{-1} \circ f = id_{A}$.

So far I have this:

We know that dom$(f^{-1} \circ f) =$ dom$(f)=A=$ dom$(id_{A})$. For any $a \in A$, $f^{-1} \circ f(a)=f^{-1}(f(a))=a=id_{A}$.

Is this enough to prove this (because the domains are equal and $f^{-1}(a) = f(a)$)?

Comment: The final line you wrote is confusing.  $f^{-1}(a)$ does not necessarily need to equal $f(a)$, in fact $f^{-1}(a)$ does not even need to be defined.  The domain of $f^{-1}$ is $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed that domains of both functions are equal and that for all $a \in A,$
 $$f^{-1} \circ f (a) = a = id(a)$$
Thus, you are done. The only step that may be missing is to justify why $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$. Besides that, everything looks good.